Create temp view multiple times or try catch if view exists and pass
We have to breakdown our SQL into smaller chunks and then call them into python functions for testing purposes. This leaves us with creating temp views for some SQL multiple times for different functions. Unfortunately I cannot avoid this scenario because company is very hard on test coverage.
Questions:

How is the performance effected if I use createOrReplaceTempView on same SQL in multiple functions? I know this command is lazy but the SQL still has to be compiled every time.
What if I use createTempView and catch the exception if the view already exists and Pass?
I am not sure which one of these is efficient. Any better ideas are welcome.

I still have to try this on databricks. Trying to get some ideas before I work on my huge SQL.

Test the performance of each option? Faster and safer than asking someone else.

In many languages, dunno about this one, catching exceptions is expensive, but then it might not happen often...

A1)
1- Using createOrReplaceTempView Multiple Times

Overwrites or creates a temporary view with the given name.
Each call ensures that the DataFrame is registered as a temporary table.
While this operation is lazy (view creation doesn't trigger computation), the associated SQL query or transformation logic is still analyzed and recompiled every time the view is created.

Things for performance to consider:

If the same view is created multiple times: PySpark will analyze and plan the associated SQL multiple times. However, the physical execution doesn't occur until an action (e.g., .count(), .show(), or .collect()) is triggered.
For large, complex SQL, repeated compilation may slightly impact performance, especially if it's done many times in a single execution.

A2) createTempView: Creates a temporary view, but throws an exception if the view name already exists.
example:
try:
    df.createTempView("my_temp_view")
except Exception as e:
    if "already exists" in str(e):  # Adjust error check to match the specific exception
        pass

Good luck :)
